# Stanford POS tagger with nltk in arabic text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to use `Stanford POS Tagger` in `NLTK 3.2.4` on arabic text using `Python 3.6`, I found a code source but I did not understand most of it because I am totally new to `Stanford POS Tagger`.

***Code Source :***

```
import os
java_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\\java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger as POS_Tag
home = 'E:\\Asmaa\\TP python\\'
_path_to_model = home + 'stanford-arabic-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar'
_path_to_jar = home + 'stanford-postagger.jar'
POS_Tag.java_options='-mx4096m'
st = POS_Tag(model_filename=_path_to_model, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)
sentence = '.شرب القط الحليب اللذيذ'
st.tag(sentence.split())
```

***The error I get :***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 'file' parameter must be specified
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:87)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:273)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 76, in tag
    return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), [])
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 99, in tag_sents
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "F:\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 136, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\\java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'E:\\Asmaa\\TP python\\stanford-postagger.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model', 'E:\\Asmaa\\TP python\\stanford-arabic-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar', '-textFile', 'C:\\Users\\2017\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpqajz7z6c', '-tokenize', 'false', '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

So what goes wrong ?

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1735#issuecomment-306145713

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in [this web page](https://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-v-using-stanford-text-analysis-tools-in-python), it was in the arabic model.

***The right code:***

```
import os
java_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\\java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger as POS_Tag
arabic_postagger = POS_Tag('models/arabic.tagger', 'stanford-postagger.jar')
sentence = '.شرب القط الحليب اللذيذ'
print(arabic_postagger.tag(sentence.split()))
```

***The result:***

> [('', 'شرب/VBD'), ('', 'القط/DTNN'), ('', 'الحليب/DTNN'), ('', 'اللذيذ/DTJJ')]

Comment: add `arabic_postagger._SEPARATOR = '/'` in order to get a properly formatted output, e.g.          `[('شرب', 'VBD'), ('القط', 'DTNN'), ('الحليب', 'DTNN'), ('اللذيذ', 'DTJJ')]`

Answer (score 2):

First upgrade your `nltk`, then on the terminal or command-prompt:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-arabic-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse \
-status_port 9005  -port 9005 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger
>>> from nltk.tokenize.stanford import CoreNLPTokenizer
>>> sttok = CoreNLPTokenizer('http://localhost:9005')
>>> stpos = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9005')
>>> text = u'انا حامل'
>>> stpos.tag(sttok.tokenize(text))
[('انا', 'DET'), ('حامل', 'NC')]
```